# How can I configure HTTPS for multiple port numbers for Apache/Tomcat on a Windows Server system?

Tags: windows, apache, ssl, tomcat, https

I am having trouble configuring HTTPS for multiple port numbers for Apache/Tomcat on a Windows Server system.

We have some web applications/sites running on an older Windows server (virtual machine). I am setting up a new virtual machine (with a slightly different domain name) for the latest versions of these applications. The new machine is running Windows Server 2016 with (64-bit versions of) Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 9.0.30. The Apache version is the ApacheHaus distribution (that was the mirror site suggested for me when I downloaded Apache, no other reason). I also installed ColdFusion (Express) because one of the applications is a Coldfusion application.

This is for the internal network only, it is not exposed to the public internet.

BEFORE adding SSL/server certificates, I was able to successfully browse to the HTTP versions, as follows:

- http://DOMAIN.NAME:80 (or without a port number); this showed the default ApacheHaus test page
- http://DOMAIN.NAME:8080; this showed the default Tomcat page
- http://DOMAIN.NAME:8500 (the default port for Coldfusion); this showed the list of folders for the Coldfusion web server, and if I added a folder name to the end of the URL displayed that Coldfusion application

From the network team at work, I have now requested and obtained a server certificate for the new domain name (URL), and the DNS entries for the new name have been set up. The certificate is from a commercial registrar. I copied the new certificate files to the new server.

The httpd.conf file in the "conf" folder for Apache references the "httpd-ssl.conf" file in the extra folder.

In the "httpd-ssl.conf" file, I added lines for the certificate file (from the registrar) and for the key file (from when I generated the request).

Now on the server, I can successfully connect to the HTTPS version of the new domain name, and it shows me the default ApacheHaus test page (over HTTPS) with no errors.

However, my attempts to also serve the port 8500 page (site) over HTTPS have failed.

In the http-ssl.conf file, I added a new section similar to the following (not showing the angle brackets around the VirtualHost tags), and I also added a "Listen 8500" line earlier in the same file:

```
VirtualHost _default_:8500
DocumentRoot "PATH-TO-COLDFUSION-TOP-LEVEL-FOLDER"
ServerName NEW-DOMAIN-NAME
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "[CERT-FILE]"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "[KEY-FILE]"
/VirtualHost
```

After restarting the Windows services for Apache and Tomcat, if I attempt to browse to the HTTPS version for port 8500:

https://DOMAIN.NAME:8500

Then, it shows me the default ApacheHaus test page instead of the Coldfusion site page.

I have tried various versions of the "VirtualHost" line (such as "*:8500", "DOMAIN-NAME:8500", etc.), and I have tried the "ServerName" line in this block with and without the port number. Any variations I have tried have either caused an error when restarting the Apache service or still displayed the default ApacheHaus test page. I can still connect to the non-HTTPS version of the site at port 8500.

If I try any of these configurations with the "8080" port number, it also shows me the default ApacheHaus test page over HTTPS (instead of the default Tomcat page).

Can anyone recommend a configuration for the second VirtualHost entry (or any other configuration changes that I need to make) to allow the Coldfusion site at port 8500 to be successfully served via HTTPS?

Comment: `http://DOMAIN.NAME:8080` shows default Tomcat page and `https://DOMAIN.NAME:8080` shows default ApacheHaus test page?

Comment: Dusan - Yes, that's correct; the HTTP page at the 8080 port is the default Tomcat test page (as expected), and the HTTPS page at 8080 is the default ApacheHaus test page (the same page as at port 80, not the TomCat page)

Comment: Is the http-ssl.conf already included in httpd.conf?